# Excel: Help Formatting Columns from Another Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to reformat an existing excel sheet in a new sheet.

The workbook has 2 sheets. Sheet 1 is called Responses and sheet 2 is called Question.

The format of the Responses sheet is:

```
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |      Question1      |     Question2    |    Question3     |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          5          |         5        |         5        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |          4          |         4        |         4        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |          3          |         3        |         3        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |          2          |         2        |         2        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          5          |          1          |         1        |         1        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

The format of the Question sheet is:

```
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |      Question       |       Value      |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      Question1      |         5        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      Question1      |         4        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |      Question1      |         3        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |      Question1      |         2        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |      Question1      |         1        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      Question2      |         5        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      Question2      |         4        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |      Question2      |         3        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |      Question2      |         2        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |      Question2      |         1        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      Question3      |         5        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      Question3      |         4        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |      Question3      |         3        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |      Question3      |         2        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |      Question3      |         1        |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

Formula to populate the ID from the Responses Sheet to the Question Sheet however it increments while I need it to follow the pattern in the Question table:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Responses!A:A")=0,"",INDIRECT("Responses!A:A"))
```

So far I can only get the first 5 responses of each column and I am not sure how to get the header value that corresponds to it in the Question column.

Here is the formula that I have so far to populate the Value column from the Responses sheet however it is limited to the values in 1 column.

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Responses!B2:B40000")=0,"",INDIRECT("Responses!B2:B40000"))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Thanks! I am using Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.12730.20252) 64-bit, Version 2004 (Build 12730.20270)(May 21st, 2020).

Comment: Hard to tell what you're after here, since you haven't asked a question (this is also not about formatting), but I'd take a stab - Are you trying to populate a Response sheet from the data in the Question sheet? That would be a simple `INDEX(MATCH())` in the cells of the body of the table in the Response sheet... it would also be helpful if you [edit] your question to include your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a recent version, this should work.

Use 'Data > Get & Transform Data > From Table/Range':

[image]

In the Power Query Editor, select the columns with the question answers in them, then use 'Transform > Any Column > Unpivot Only Selected Columns':

[image]

Use 'Home > Close & Load' and you should get what you need:

[image]

EDIT:

If the final order of the data is imported, you can sort the data in the Power Query Editor just before hitting Close & Load.